# Arranging three groups around a table so that no two people wearing the same color shirt are adjacent

Tags: combinatorics, permutations

Say there are 10 blue shirt people, 8 red shirt people, and 5 green shirt people. How many ways are there to arrange them around a table (circle) so that no two people of same shirt color sit next to each other?

What I think: I tried to approach this in the same way as if it was just alternating two groups, where id seat the blue shirt people first giving me $9!8!5!$. Is this right? If not how would I approach this

Comment: I think I saw this question elsewhere on this site but can't find it. I would start by finding the ways to seat the 10 blues in the 23 seats. Not too many of those since you need a gap of at least one between each two blues.

Comment: **Strategy:**  Arrange the people in blue shirts in a circle.  This creates $10$ spaces in which to place the people with red shirts or green shirts.  Determine at least how many spaces must be filled by people with red shirts so that no two people with the same color shirt will be adjacent.  Fill any empty spaces with people wearing green shirts, then distribute the remaining people with green shirts in such a way that no two people with red shirts are adjacent.

Comment: So to seat the blue shirts there would be 9! way right? Where I'm struggling is trying to formulate a equation for how many ways I can put down the red or green because there are more seats than people that work as an option.

Comment: You are correct that there are $9!$ ways to arrange the people in blue shirts.  Worry about the seats later.  You can place people in seats after you arrange them.  First, place the ten people in blue shirts in a circle, which creates the ten gaps where you can place the people in red shirts and blue shirts.  See if you can follow the strategy I outlined above.  Please update your question with any attempts you have made.

Answer (score 2):

- Designate one blue shirt as *true blue* for reference point
- Place $10$ blues in a circle with gaps
- Fill $10$ gaps with $10$ blanks
- $3$ extra can either be in one, two, or three slots, eg if in one slot, colored red-green-red-green or green-red-green-red. So placed in $2\cdot10$ ways. Placing the remaining green in $\binom 93$ ways completes this pattern. And if on three slots,will have two blanks each in 3 slots , with green-red or red-green. Thus placement will be in $2^3\binom{10}3\times \binom72$
- Work out similarly if the three extras are in two slots, add up for all the possible patterns and multiply by $9!8!5!$ for people placement

**Added** working for case 3

- RGR, RG/GR: $2*10*9*\binom83$
- GRG, RG/GR: $2*10*9*\binom82$

Before multiplying by $9!8!5!$, the total comes to $36960$

Comment: I am having a bit of trouble following your calculation.  I have written an answer so that you can compare your answer with mine.  Please check whether one of us has made an error.

Comment: @N.F.Taussig: i have added working for case 3, and the total. Do you see any infirmities in the approach ?  I am on holiday, i will try and check yours as soon as I can

Comment: Our answers agree.  When I first looked at your answer, I must have been too tired to understand your reasoning, but it made sense yesterday once you fixed the typographical error in the three slots calculation.  Enjoy your holiday.

Comment: @N.F.Taussig: Okay then, thumbs up !

Answer (score 1):

These kind of problems are solved by a technique known as dynamic programming in computer science. You don't need to know what that is to solve this problem though. I'm gonna explain the whole idea in a simplistic manner below.

suppose we force the first person to sit in the circle to be blue. Then we try to fill the remaining people incrementally.

We define $b_{x, y, z}$ as the number of ways x blue shirts, y red shirts and z green shirts can fill the remainder of the circle such that the first person to sit at the table can't be blue and the last person won't be blue naturally (since the first of the circle was fixed blue initially).

Furthermore we define, $r_{x, y, z}$ as the number of ways x blue shirts, y red and z green shirts can fill the remainder of the circle such that the first person to sit at the table can't be red and the last person won't be blue (for the same resason as before).

And finally we define, $g_{x, y, z}$ as the number of ways x blue, y red and z green shirst can fill the remainder of the circle such that the first person won't be green and the last person won't be blue.

We have:

$$b_{x, y, z} = r_{x, y - 1, z} + g_{x, y, z - 1}.$$
Because if you can't put a blue person as the first one, you either have to put a red one or a green one.
$$r_{x, y, z} = b_{x - 1, y, z} + g_{x, y, z - 1}.$$
$$g_{x, y, z} = b_{x - 1, y, z} + r_{x, y - 1, z}.$$
The latter two recurrence relations have a simillar logic to the first one.

The only remaining thing is to find a basis for these recurrence relations and then start filling a three-dimensional table bottom-up to find out the value for b_{9, 8, 5} which would be the answer to your question.

The basis for these relations are:
$$b_{0, ..., ...} = 0$$
$$r_{..., 0, ...} = 0$$
$$g_{..., ..., 0} = 0$$

Answer (score 1):

Suppose that Adam is one of the people wearing a blue shirt.  We will use him as our reference point.

Before we do so, let's begin by arranging ten blue balls, eight red balls, and five green balls in a circle so that no two balls of the same color are adjacent.  Arrange the ten blue balls in a circle.  Place Adam's name on one of the blue balls so that we can use that ball as a reference point.

Placing the ten blue balls in a circle creates ten spaces, one to the left of each ball, where the red balls and green balls can be placed to separate the blue balls.

At least seven of these spaces must be filled with red balls since if only six spaces were filled with red balls, then there would be three red balls in one space or two red balls in two spaces, making it impossible to separate the red balls with green balls once we filled the remaining four spaces between two blue balls with green balls.

*The eight red balls are placed in eight of the ten spaces between two blue balls*:  There are $\binom{10}{8}$ ways to place the eight red balls in eight of the ten spaces between two blue balls.  To separate the blue balls, we must a green ball in each of the remaining two spaces between two blue balls.  That leaves three green balls to distribute.  Since no green balls can be adjacent, we must place the remaining green balls in spaces between two blue balls already containing a red ball.  To ensure that no two of the remaining three green balls are adjacent, we can either place them in three of the eight spaces between two blue balls where we have already placed a red ball or we can place two of them in one of these eight spaces and place one of them in another of these spaces.  There are $\binom{8}{3}$ ways to select three of the spaces.  In each such space, we can place a green ball to the left or right of the red ball that is there.  There are eight ways to select a red ball to be surrounded by two green balls, seven ways to choose the other red ball that will be adjacent to a green ball, and two ways to choose on which of that red ball to place the green ball.  Hence, there are
$$\binom{10}{8}\left[\binom{8}{3}2^3 + \binom{8}{1}\binom{7}{1}\binom{2}{1}\right]$$
such distributions.

*The eight red balls are placed in seven of the ten spaces between two blue balls*: There are $\binom{10}{7}$ ways to select which seven of the ten spaces between two blue balls will receive at least one red ball and seven ways to select which of these spaces will receive two red balls.  To ensure that the blue balls are separated, we must place a green ball in each of the remaining three spaces between two blue balls.  To ensure that the two adjacent red balls are separated, we must place a green ball between them.  That leaves one green ball to distribute.  To ensure the green balls are separated, it must be placed in one of the seven spaces between two blue balls that already contains at least one red ball.  It can be placed in the same space that already contains two red balls separated by a green ball in two ways, so that the order is grgr or rgrg as we proceed clockwise from the blue ball with Adam's name on it.  Otherwise, it can be placed in one of the six spaces containing a single red ball.  In that space, it can be placed to the left or right of the red ball that is already there.  Hence, there are
$$\binom{10}{7}\binom{7}{1}\left[\binom{2}{1} + \binom{6}{1}\binom{2}{1}\right]$$
such distributions.

Thus, there are
$$\binom{10}{8}\left[\binom{8}{3}2^3 + \binom{8}{1}\binom{7}{1}\binom{2}{1}\right] + \binom{10}{7}\binom{7}{1}\left[\binom{2}{1} + \binom{6}{1}\binom{2}{1}\right]$$
ways to place ten blue balls, eight red balls, and five green balls in a circle up to rotation.

Placing Adam in the position of the blue ball with his name on it, we can place the remaining nine people in blue shirts in the positions occupied by the remaining blue balls in $9!$ ways, the eight people in red shirts in $8!$ ways, and the five people in green shirts in $5!$ ways as we proceed clockwise around the table from Adam.  Hence, the ten people in blue shirts, eight people in red shirts, and five people in green shirts can be arranged around the table in
$$9!8!5!\left\{\binom{10}{8}\left[\binom{8}{3}2^3 + \binom{8}{1}\binom{7}{1}\binom{2}{1}\right] + \binom{10}{7}\binom{7}{1}\left[\binom{2}{1} + \binom{6}{1}\binom{2}{1}\right]\right\}$$
ways.

Comment: When you say that at least 7 spaces must be filled by red balls, do you mean **only red** ? Because 6 could be only red and one could have RGRG/GRGR

Comment: My logic is that there are 3 extra R/G balls, suitable combos of which can be accommodated in one, two or three slots.

Comment: @trueblueanil After I placed the blue balls in a circle, creating 10 spaces, I distributed the red balls.  In the first case, I placed 8 of them in separate spaces, put green balls in the other two spaces between two blues, then distributed the other 3 green balls to spaces already holding a red ball.  In the second case, I used 7 spaces for the red balls, with 2 of them placed in the same space, placed green balls in the remaining 3 spaces between two blues and the space between the 2 red balls, then distributed the remaining green ball to a space which already held at least one red ball.

Comment: Could you just list the *clumps* of red and green used for each of your cases, the checking would be easy. For example, you aren't having a clump rgrg/grgr with solos 6r,3g

Comment: I am too sleep-deprived to sort through this now.  Please enjoy your holiday.  When I have had enough sleep, I will compare our answers to find the source of the discrepancy.

Comment: Thanks, i can now enjoy my holiday, the holiday brain is too fickle for this work, as is a sleep deprived one  !$\;\;$:)